# Join tables and filter by multiple condtions with Dapper in asp.net core mvc

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I want to query join two tables with multiple conditions

```
  string sql = "Select l.*, c.FirstName_CompanyName from dbo.Loan l left join Customer c on  l.CustId=c.CustId where LoanAccountNo > 0 ";
```

When I implemented the above code, but I discovered I need to filter **Loan** table by **Approved** and **Deleted** But I can't seem to get it right.

The code below is what I have tried but didn't work

```
string sql = "Select l.*, c.FirstName_CompanyName from dbo.Loan WHERE Delete = 0 AND Approve = 1 l left join Customer c on  l.CustId=c.CustId where LoanAccountNo > 0 ";
```

```
{"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Delete'."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code, there is a type error in the code, you added delete dna approve condition in between Loan table and alias l

```
string sql = "Select l.*, c.FirstName_CompanyName from dbo.Loan l WHERE l.Delete = 0 AND l.Approve = 1 left join Customer c on  l.CustId=c.CustId where LoanAccountNo > 0 ";
```